# FFT on a signal with a length that is not a multiple of the period of its harmonics

Tags: fourier-transform, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis, signal-processing

I was very surprised to find an apparent limitation to a FFT on a simple signal.

Let's consider a timeseries made of L=100 points, and simply composed of the sum of two sinus waves: one with a wavelength of 7 points, the other with a wavelength of 13 points (the phase or amplitude does not matter).

If you compute the FFT of this signal, you won't find exactly the two harmonics, because L is not an exact multiple of 7 or 13.

How do you deal with this problem? Interpolation of the data on a higher resolution?

Edit : this problem can be "minimized" with zero padding

Comment: Google "zero padding"

Comment: Thank you ! Problem solved.

Comment: Problem solved? Problem starts! While you are "padding" do not forget to "window"!